# How to read the data from list object which consists of array in it

Tags: c#, asp.net

After creating the `leaguelist` in the code below, how can I access the values in the list in order to populate another list?

I need to pass the values of the list to another list and send it to a view.

```
List<Notification> notificationlist = new List<Notification>(); 
notificationlist.Add(new Notification { date = leaguename = leaguevenue = teamwon = })
```

What i am trying to do is read the values from `leaguelist` and I need to access the data of that list in `notificationlist` to populate the values for date, leaguename, leaguevenue, etc.

```
 List<string[]> leaguelist = new List<string[]>();
        while (count != 0)
        {
            Int16 id = Convert.ToInt16(sportds.Tables[0].Rows[count-1]["sports_details_id"].ToString());

            using (SqlDataAdapter leagueDetails = new SqlDataAdapter("select league_name, league_details_venue,league_details_date from leagues, league_details where sports_details_id1 in ('" + id+ "') or sports_details_id2 in ('" + id + "')", sqlConnection1))
            {
                DataSet leagues = new DataSet();
                leagueDetails.Fill(leagues).ToString();

                lname = leagues.Tables[0].Rows[0]["league_name"].ToString();
                lvenue = leagues.Tables[0].Rows[0]["league_details_venue"].ToString();
                ldate = leagues.Tables[0].Rows[0]["league_details_date"].ToString();

                string[] fields = new string[3];
                fields[0] = lname;
                fields[1] = lvenue;
                fields[2] = ldate;
                leaguelist.Add(fields);                   
            }
            count = count - 1}
```

Please help me with this !!

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but the way you're accessing the sql results is only ever going to return the first row.  Using `Tables[0].Rows[0]` will return the first row only.  If you want to get all of the rows, you'll need to loop throw the `Table[0].Rows` collection and read each one.

Comment: @JohnM.Wright Thanks for that john, i have the data that i need in the first row, so no issue with that. I have all the data that i need stored in leaguelist. I just need to know how to access that data and store it in another valriable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you can walk through the list and read the values in a `foreach` loop and add it to the `notificationList`:

```
List<Notification> notificationlist = new List<Notification>();

foreach (string[] fields in leagueList)
{
    var lname = fields[0];
    var lvenue = fields[1];
    var ldate = fields[2];

    Console.WriteLine($"League {lname} at {lvenue} on {ldate}");
    notificationsList.Add(new Notification
                              {
                               date = ldate, 
                               leaguename = lname, 
                               leaguevenue = lvenue
                              };
}
```

You can also use LINQ, like this:

```
notificationsList.AddRange(
            leagueList.Select(fields => new Notificationnew Notification
                              {
                               date = fields[2], 
                               leaguename = fields[0], 
                               leaguevenue = fields[1]
                              });
```

Comment: M.Wright I need to pass the values of the list to another list and send it to a view. List<Notification> notificationlist = new List<Notification>();
            notificationlist.Add(new Notification
            {   date =
                leaguename =
                leaguevenue =
                teamwon = 
            });

Comment: Please update your question to better explain what you're looking for. Include examples of what you've tried and the code snippet you added in your comment.

Comment: M.wright okay , what i am trying to do is read the values from leaguelist and i need to access the data of that list in notificationlist which i mentioned in the comment. values for date, leaguename, leaguevenue are stored in leaguelist. Thats the reason i need to access it. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Good to hear!  Don't forget to accept the answer (click the checkmark next to it) if it correctly answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

This might help, you can select a single element from your list and add it to your notification list.  You could use a for loop to iterate through your list and do something like this.

```
var s = leaguelist[0];
        notificationList.Add(new Notification
        {
            date = s[0],
            leagename = s[1],
            leaguevenue = s[2]
        });
```